# Number of components of a node in Networkx

Tags: python, networkx

How can I compute the number of connected components surrounding a given node in a network?

Example: suppose A is connected to B. A is also connected to C and D, and C and D are connected to each other as well. In this case, node A has 2 connected components including [B] and [C,D].

Comment: What does it mean for a connected component to "surround" a node? A node can only be a part of one connected component.

Comment: Just updated the question @aryamccarthy

Comment: So your question could be reframed as this: if I remove node **A** from a connected graph, what are the components that exist?

Comment: Not exactly. Because it may be the case that if we remove node A, the remaining neighbors still form one component. @aryamccarthy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I understand your intent now.

Let's use Padgett's Florentine families as a model.

[image: Florentine families graph]

Here, of the neighbors of the Medici node, only Ridolfi and Tornabuoni are neighbors of each other.

```
# Setup
import networkx as nx
G = nx.florentine_families_graph()  # Or whatever else your graph is.

# Computation
node_id = 'Medici'  # Your nodes are probably identified by a number.
ego = nx.ego_graph(G, n=node_id, center=False)
components = nx.connected_components(ego)
for c in components:
    print(c)
# {'Acciaiuoli'}
# {'Ridolfi', 'Tornabuoni'}
# {'Albizzi'}
# {'Salviati'}
# {'Barbadori'}
```

The ego graph is all immediate neighbors of a node `n`. `center=False` excludes `n` from that graph. From there, we find the components.